# Show short text of content

Tags: posts

I need to get the last 2 posts from `News` Category and show them in sidebar. I use the code below

```
<?php $news_id = get_cat_ID('News');
    if($news_id) {
        echo '<div class="entry-title"><a href="'.get_category_link( $news_id ).'">'.get_the_category_by_ID( $news_id ).'</a></div>'; 

        $recent_news = wp_get_recent_posts( array('numberposts' => 2, 'category' => $news_id, 'post_status' => 'publish'));

        if ($recent_news) {
            echo '<ul class="sidebar-posts-list">';
            foreach ($recent_news as $news_item) {
                echo '<li><div class="item-title">' .  $news_item["post_title"].'</div>';
                echo '<div class="item-text">' . wp_trim_words( $news_item["post_content"], 20 ) . '</div>';            
                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($news_item["ID"]) . '" class="read-more">Read more</a></li>';  
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
}?>
```

but I'm not sure that using `wp_trim_words( $news_item["post_content"], 20 )` is the right way to get what I want. It works but I'm not sure it's right.  Maybe there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential issue I see with that is if the content contains [Shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

You can [strip Shortcodes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/strip_shortcodes) before passing it to `wp_trim_words` if you want them removed, or alternately, if you want to maintain them you can [apply the Shortcodes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) beforehand.

You may also want to check that `$news_item["post_excerpt"]` is not empty, in case a custom excerpt has been entered in place of your auto-trimmed version.

Comment: So, can I just add `strip_shortcodes` function in my code like `wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes ($news_item["post_content"]), 20 )`? Will it be enough for correct work? And I don't undestand why, but my `$news_item["post_excerpt"]` is empty in every `$news_item`.

Comment: Yes, that will work. `post_excerpt` will be empty unless you manually create an excerpt in the Excerpt field when editing a post. The field may be hidden on your post edit screen, click the Screen Options tab in the upper right corner and tick the Excerpt box to see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and the explanation. I think, I don't need `post_excerpt` here, I think, using `wp_trim_words( strip_shortcodes ($news_item["post_content"]), 20 )` will be enough for me.